# UIButton not response to UIControlEventTouchDown when in tabbar rect

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have this strange behavior in my App, I put a `UIButton` in the bottom area of a viewController, and add `UIControlEventTouchDown`  action to the controller. When I touched, the touchDown event will not fire immediately, but as I move my finger a bit or touch up, it will be called.

I don't know what's wrong with the touch event, I override the

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

method, but it will not be called as well.
So I made a sample code to show this behavior, and found it work well when the button is not in the `UITabbar` area, I put the example project code [here](https://github.com/lxzhh/buttonTouchEventTest/archive/master.zip).

Comment: I looked at your project and it all works as expected. You should update your post with some images and code snippets to clarify what exactly doesn't work. The orange button in your code outputs "buttonTouchDown" as soon as it is pressed, even if not released.

Comment: @Krumelur Thanks for your response. Did you run the project on your device, I run it on iPhone5 iOS7. It works well in simulator. And notice the viewController with button at bottom, when you first touched, there is no response,  it will not become blue and output log unless you move a bit or release.